# Julia : create an arrays in for loop

Tags: arrays, julia

l want to create an array having this structure

k[1]= 1

k[2]= 2

k[3]= 3

k[4]= 4

l tried it in this way but it's not working

```
n= 10

for i in 1:n
 k[i]= i
end
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: You often don't actually need an array (that occupies memory) and can use a range instead, e.g. `k = -5:5`. Then you can do `k[3]` and get `2` back, which is the third element of the range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You havent initialized the array, so calling k[1] or k[2] or k[n] wont return an error

You should either:

```
n= 10
k = Array(Int64, n) #or Float64 or Any instead of Int64
for i in 1:n
    k[i]= i
end
```

or you could

```
n= 10
k = []
for i in 1:n
    push!(k,i)
end
```

I suggest the former, the other method would be more suited if you woulnt be able to determine the size of the array beforehand

Comment: I like the second method even when I do know the size. However, you should define the array initially with the correct argument type, e.g. `k = Int[ ]` in this example.

Comment: It seems the first version you give doesn't work in Julia 1.6+ (maybe earlier versions too; gives a MethodError).  Instead, one can use the `Array{Int64}(undef, n)` as described [in the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Core.Array-Tuple{UndefInitializer,%20Any}), to make an array of set dimensions (1 dimension, size n) and type (Int64), with uninitialized values.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to get the specific array you want is this:

```
k = collect(1:10)
```

If you want to define an array in a loop, then you first need to preallocate the array, e.g. using `k = zeros(10)` and then specify the values:

```
n = 10
k = zeros(n)
for i = 1:n
    k[i] = i
end
```

Answer (score 3):

See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Arrays_and_tuples#Uninitialized

"Using comprehensions and generators to create arrays"

```
k = [i for i in 1:10]
```

Answer (score -3):

How do you know it's not working? Try evaluating `k`:

```
n= 10

for i in 1:n
 k[i]= i
end

k

10-element Array{Int64,1}: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

A more succinct way of doing the same thing:

```
collect(1:10)
```

Comment: In 0.4.6 this snippet will throw an UndefVarError, and I suspect that in other versions too. The basic asumption is that the array isn't initialized in the question, and the author is just testing Matlab behaivour, where this works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Embarrassing mistake. I ran the code in a Jupyter notebook -- where `k` was in fact defined in another cell.